# DRY in Vue.js + Vuex

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vue.js, vuex

Which way you approach repetitions in your code when dealing with *Vue.js + Vuex*. I have two mutations that are ridicuously similar to each other.

> First one is for Services:

```
function setServiceItem(state, {model, value}) {
  const service = state.order_services
  service[model] = value
  if (model === 'service') {
    service.unit_price = value.price
  }
  updatePrice(service)
}
```

> Second one is for Materials:

```
function setMaterialItem(state, {model, value}) {
  const material = state.order_material
  material[model] = value
  if (model === 'material') {
    material.unit_price = value.price
  }
  updatePrice(material)
}
```

Both of these are very similar but due to the way ***Vuex*** is designed I am very limited in the way I can merge two of these into one mutation rather then two.

I could have added 3rd parameter such as location and do something like so

```
function setMisc(state, {model, value, location, eventForPriceAssignment}) {
  const item = state[loc]
  item[model] = value
  if (model === eventForPriceAssignment) {
    item.unit_price = value.price
  }
  updatePrice(material)
}
```

But that would make the function much more complex as well, and would require me to pass more parameters on each commit that would completely wipy any benefit of **DRY**.

Answer (score 0):

My view (opinion based), is that the more verbose way is the *correct* way. When you use the vue dev tool, seeing the mutation by name helps with debugging. However in cases where I'm updating an object with many params, I have used the later.

Answer (score 0):

The real question is whether that logic belongs in one mutator method or if it should be re-factored out into separate methods. For me a mutator called `setMaterialItem` should mutate the state of a property called `materialItem`, but it actually looks like it does a bunch of other stuff on an object called `order_material`, how you counteract that depends on exactly what you are attempting to do, maybe you need to use an [action](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/actions.html) or maybe break your store in to [modules](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/modules.html), perhaps a `mixin` would allow for better code reuse, it's difficult to say without having a more detailed idea about how your app is structured.

While principles like DRY are great for guiding your development, remember it's just as important that your app is logically structured, is easily maintainable and makes sense to you, then you can cut yourself a bit of slack when your code isn't perfect.